# How to bind, populate, and fetch selected value on submit of <select> with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSON object on the scope that looks like this:

```
  $scope.colors = [
    {'colorCode': 'R', 'colorName': 'Red'},
    {'colorCode': 'Y', 'colorName': 'Yellow'},
    {'colorCode': 'P', 'colorName': 'Pink'},
  ];
```

I would like to bind a `<select>` to this so that it looks like this

```
<select>
   <option value="R">Red</option>
   <option value="Y">Yellow</option>
   <option value="P">Pink</option>
</select>
```

What I've done is this:

```
<select
   ng-model="model.selectedcolor"
   ng-options="c.colorCode as c.colorName for c in colors">
</select>
```

However, when I inspect the html it is creating HTML like this:

```
<select>
   <option value="0">Red</option>
   <option value="1">Yellow</option>
   <option value="2">Pink</option>
</select>
```

**Questions**

1. How can I pre-select the second item in the drop down (in this case, Yellow)
2. How can I have `value="R"...` in the HTML
3. When I submit the form, will I be able to get the selected value by `$scope.model.selectedcolor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-options` is arguably a better alternative than `ng-repeat`-ing `<option>`. This is because the `ng-model` can be bound to an object (of the `value as` value).

You have specified it correctly.

Angular would, under the covers, properly map the selected `<option>` value to the right object for you, and you don't even need to care about what the `value` attribute of `<option>` is set to - this is to answer your **question #2**.

On **question #1**, to (pre-)select an option, modify the `ng-model`-bound property accordingly. This will "drive" the View. In your case, set:

```
$scope.model.selectedcolor = "Y";
```

On **question #3**, it depends on what you mean by "submit a form". You typically don't classically submit a form to the server with an SPA (another reason, why you shouldn't care about that `<option value="1">` for `"Y"`). `$scope.model.selectedcolor` will be set to the selected `colorcode`.

**As an off-topic:**

You could bind your `select` to the actual `color` object, and not just the `colorcode` property:

```
<select ng-model="model.selectedColor"
        ng-options="c as c.colorName for c in colors">
</select>
```

Then, you can operate with the entire object. For example, to preselect and to submit, you would do:

```
$scope.model.selectedColor = $scope.colors[1]; // second one is selected

$scope.submit = function(){
   var colorcode = $scope.model.selectedColor.colorcode;
   // post colorcode to server
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`? The latter gives me errors while the former works.

Comment: Also, by default there is an empty option with code `<option value="?"></option>` Is there a way to get rid of this? I've ensured that `colors` only has three items.

Comment: This is because your `ng-model`-bound property is not set to anything, so the `<select>` directive opts to create a blank property. Either pre-select the `ng-model`, or specify a blank property with `<option value="">select color...</option>`. This blank option will set the model to `undefined`

Comment: Yup, that goes away when I pre-select something. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To populate your select:

```
<select ng-model="model.selectedcolor"  ng-options="color.colorCode as color.colorName for color in colors" >

</select>
```

In your controller:

To preselect:

```
$scope.model = {
     selectedcolor : "Y"
}
```

When you submit:

Try accessing:

```
$scope.model.selectedcolor
```

It will give you `Y`

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sepegu/1/edit?html,js,output)**

**[DEMO WITH SUBMIT](http://jsbin.com/sepegu/3/edit)**

Comment: This seems to work, however, in the select box there is an empty option with code `<option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>` Is there a way to get rid of the empty option?